# Exception handling in jsr286 portlet

Tags: java, spring, exception, portlet

**I am trying exception handling in spring portlet based UI application**,

I have used spring `globalexception handling` using `@ControllerAdvice`.

It works fine in servlet based application but its not working in portlet application.I have noticed that spring container has not processed `@ControllerAdvice` in portlet. I tried searching in internet on the same issue but no luck.

**Is there any other way to handle exceptions in portlet applications?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Spring Based Portlet, tried @ControllerAdvice, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The `Portlet` support in Spring is rapidly declining, with very little code or documentation of such. You'll notice that the `DispatcherPortlet` auto-registers an instance of `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`, not the newer `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`.

Even if you manually define an instance of the latter in your `portlet.xml` file, it won't get picked up by the `DispatcherPortlet` because it specifically looks for implementers of the `org.springframework.web.portlet.HandlerExceptionResolver`, which is a different hierarchy than the `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver` (of which `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` is a descendent).